# Get node after replacing it with a clone of itself

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an html element that I'm replacing with a clone of itself to remove event listeners. However, I still want to interact with it after I've replaced it. Unfortunately,

```js
node.replaceWith(node.cloneNode(true))
```

makes node link to an element that doesn't exist. Is there any way I can get the element that is now where it was? I know I can circumvent this by giving it an id before and querying for it after, but it feels like there should be a better way.

Comment: You'll need to store the clone before replacing and then reassign `node`.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to store the clone before replacing and then reassign `node`.

To avoid having the `clone` hanging around you can wrap the method in a function that returns the clone.

```js
function replaceSelf(node) {
  const clone = node.cloneNode(true);
  node.replaceWith(clone);

  return clone;
}

let node = document.getElementById('to-clone');
node = replaceSelf(node);

node.style.backgroundColor = 'cyan';
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="to-clone">paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

```
node = node.replaceWith(node.cloneNode(true))
```

with this

```
node.replaceWith(node.cloneNode(true))
```

Because [`replaceWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith) returns `undefined`

Comment: That was already what I was doing, just had a typo on the question. Thanks for pointing it out!